# Basic vs advanced version of GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

**For a tutorial site, I would like to offer the "project files" for each project as a downloadable GitHub repo. However, I would like to:**

- Offer a *basic* version/repo
- Offer an *advanced* version/repo (basic version, plus some additional features)

How can this be achieved with Git/GitHub? In particular, I may make changes to the basic version later on, and I would like those changes to be applied to the advanced version as well. So I don't think forking is an option? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have one repo with two branches, the `basic` and the `advanced` branch. When you commit changes to the `basic` branch, you can then simply merge those changes into the `advanced` branch, resolve the potential merge conflicts, and are done.

If you do not wish to have two branches but want two repos, that works fine, too. Assuming you use GitHub, simply fork the basic repo and create the advanced repo from that. If you make changes to the basic repo, you can then create a pull request (PR) for the advanced repo and merge the changes via the PR.
If you use raw git, you can achieve this by having one repo locally with two branches, and push those branches to two remote repos, by adding them both as upstreams.